# How can I make requestBody properties optional in OpenAPI?

Tags: python, swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I have an OpenAPI3 POST method implemented in **python flask** which has a requestBody as follows:

```
/DoSomething:
  post:
    operationId: postDoSomething
    requestBody:
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyBody'
      required: true

components:
  schemas:

    MyBody:
      type: object
        properties:
          Images:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Image'
          Ids:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Ids'
          Date:
            type: string
            format: date-time
```

I need the properties (Images, Ids, Date) to be optional parameters.

When I post to this from a C# application with the Images array as null for example I get the following error on the server.

```
validation error: None is not of type 'array'
```

How can I make the parameters optional?

Comment: They are optional by default. Please post your C# code.

Comment: As Helen indicated, they are optional. The problem seems to be that as you said you are passing the Images array as null. Instead, exclude the Images array all together.

If you have parameters that are not optional, you should indicate that they are required. https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#required